# Using Intent to communicate with an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Using intents to communicate between two activities seems not straightforward. Regardless of where (probably in onResume()) I place the check for intent I end up in a situation where it is impossible to distinguish between the call where passing intent took place along the startActivity() and the call when the device was rotated (or put through onPause() and onResume() cycle in general) later because the intent is still available.

How do I deal with the problem above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do

[`setIntent(intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)

to change the intent that you recieved. So you could add an extra or set a completely different intent.
The next time you do getintent you will get the intent that you have set

Comment: I see, suppose this is an alternative to setting a flag on rotation, that will work too. Thank you Nandeesh.

Answer (score 1):

You always get the intent that called the activity. On a configuration change like rotating the display `onConfigurationChanged` is called. Check here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

You can use that to distinguish if it is a rotation change or not.

Comment: if onconfigurationchanged is called, activity does not restart

Comment: You are right, and there is more, because if I unlock the phone and the activity is visible the intent is still the same. So setting the intent as you suggested might be the way to do it.